# clarification of initialization in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, uniform-initialization

I am really getting confused in following examples:

```
#include <iostream>
class C {
    public:
    int a,b;
};
int main() {
    C c{3,6};
    std::cout<<c.a<<'\n';
    std::cout<<c.b<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine and gives the expected outcome. But if I modify the above code like below.

```
#include <iostream>
class C {
    int a,b;
    public:
        int get_a(){
            return a;
        }
        int get_b(){
            return b;
        }
};
int main(){
    C c{3,6};
    std::cout<<c.get_a()<<'\n';
    std::cout<<c.get_b()<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program compiler shows multiple errors. Why uniform initialization allowed in first program but not in second? Where I am wrong?

Comment: In the second case the class member variables are `private` (implicitely), and can't be accessed for direct initializaiton.

Comment: In general:  the errors are supposed to indicate what's wrong ... it's often useful to show them. But specifically - you changed the data members from public to private.

Comment: @Mat: If I add parametrized ctor then it works fine. Compiler complains about not no matching function for call to 'C::C(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default c++ **`class`** members are `private`, so without specifying you get a private variable. Because you made the types private you do not get the aggregate-initialization for free anymore so you need to write your own  constructor for this class:

```
class C{
    C(int _a, int _b):
    a(_a), b(_b)
    {}
};
```

You just need to fix the namespacing for the `cout` and your code should compile fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d69f4f141d2bcd2

From the standard:

> [dcl.init.aggr] An *aggregate* is an array or a class with no user-provided constructors, no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions

In the first code you only had public variables so the code worked because you had an aggregate, making the variable private is what caused the problem because it was no longer an aggregate according to the above definition.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are `private` in your second example and are therefore inaccessible from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the line `int a,b;` into the `public:` scope like the first example.

You also need `std::` in front of `cout`

```
#include <iostream>
class C {
    public:
        int a,b;     //Make public
        int get_a(){
            return a;
        }
        int get_b(){
            return b;
        }
};
int main(){
    C c{3,6};
    std::cout<<c.get_a()<<'\n';   //use namespace std::
    std::cout<<c.get_b()<<'\n';   //use namespace std::
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the modified version of the code, you moved the `public:` label so the `a` and `b` data members are no longer public. Hence, they cannot be referenced from outside the class, even not implicitly by an initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

The first code worked because the data members `a` and `b` were public, so they could be accessed from outside the class. However, in the second code, they are declared as private, so they cannot be accessed from outside the class. Either declare them as public again, or use a constructor as follows (if you still want them as private):

```
 C(int x,int y)   // This is a parameterised constructor
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }
```

And initialise them as `C c(3,6);`

Comment: Note that you can still use the `C c{3,6}` syntax with this constructor.

Comment: @shuttle87: Gives me an error: `error: in C++98 'c' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'|`.

Comment: In c++98 you do indeed need to use the `c(3,6)` syntax, in later versions c++0x and later the preferred way is to use the uniform initialization syntax. Depending on the compiler/version this might require a compiler flag to be allowed.